How to resolve garage humidity levels?
I am in the UK. My garage is attached to my house and was at one point in time stables or similar, it is a split building with two levels, the main workshop and the attic/roof space above. One wall of the garage is currently retaining the garden on the other side of it - the wall is probably half buried under the garden and has had a concrete pour as a cap.
We only moved in last year so have been trying to just see how everything works without messing with it. I do a lot of woodworking and I have noticed that the garage is very humid the majority of the year (today it is about 50% RH outside and hitting 85% inside the garage). It is split level, with an attic space that seems fine and whose rafters run over the wall plate sufficiently that there is clear space for air to circulate through them without letting weather in (no soffits installed).
Part of the garage floor has been covered with concrete, the rest is the original brickwork. The level of the garage floor is also below the paved driveway outside the opposite wall (the lower course of bricks are visibly 'wet' - i.e. darker shade and relatively 'soft') and is, as above, significantly lower on the garden side wall.
So, do we think that the best course of action would probably be to excavate the soil currently up against the far wall, line it, backfill with gravel and a french drain type affair to run it off onto the road & to either install a french drain on the opposite exterior side to help take some of the water away from the wall or to lower the level of the paved driveway (it will need re-doing at some point in the next 5 years as is)?
Some of my woodworking projects are suffering from mould, others not so much, but it's clear the humidity is far too high throughout the year and is creating the perfect grounds for mould and mildew, let alone what it's doing to the structural integrity of the garage itself.
Appreciate the thoughts!
EDIT: I'm attaching a picture as suggested to help frame this a bit. To answer some other questions observations - at the moment it's about 25c outside and about 21c inside the garage.
There is no real ventilation in the space - when I open all the doors to let air through for about 2 hours, the humidity drops a bit, and then rises back to the high levels within an hour.
The wall against the garden is very clearly damp, with staining and wet to the touch.
If I was to dig down in the garden to get a drain in, can I just back fill with the soil again or best to use gravel?
Thank again everyone


Might just need ventilation.  50% outside and 85% inside sounds like the air is not changing enough(also depends on temperature difference)

Thanks @clvrmnky, I've added a picture and some clarifiers above if that helps.

Thank you @crip659 definitely not enough ventilation, outlined some more above, but that garden side wall is really wet. Think ventilation will only help so far

Ventilation is not a cure all, but it is usually the cheapest and fastest way to start reducing the damp.  You just need a place/vent for air to come in and another place opposite side for air to go out.  Will probably still need drains/sealing, but ventilation can reduce the humidity in the mean time, and is needed afterwards anyway.

I agree that the best way to get rid of wall moisture is getting rid of the water behind it.  You don't have to remove all the soil, you only need to dig down wide and far enough to get a drain in.
If it is significantly cooler in the basement, the relative humidity will automatically be higher.  Cooler air is more "humid" because cooler air holds less moisture, so for a given moisture content it will have a higher relative humidity.  That is why it is so dry in your house in the winter.

Thanks so much for this. Once the drain is in do you think I should backfill above it with gravel and liner etc, or cover back with soil? Just concerned about making sure the garden doesn't slip and take the wall with it.

I think soil is fine if you aren't clay.  You may want a surface drain as well, keep water from soaking in.
